# Infinite TranslateX CSS is not working as required in Website

Tags: html, css

I have added the infinite translateX animation in my website but it is not working as expected. Both list animate is same direction sometimes and also show whitespace after completing. It is not infinite animation.

**This is my code:**

```css
.office-slider-list {
    font-size: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    will-change: transform;
}

.office-slider-list li {
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    letter-spacing: -.01em;
    color: #252227;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    margin-right: 2vw;
    line-height: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.office-slider-list.office-slider-list--1 {
    animation: scrollLeft linear infinite;
    animation-duration: 40s !important;
}

ul.office-slider-list.office-slider-list--2 {
    animation: scrollRight linear infinite;
    animation-duration: 40s !important;
}

 @keyframes scrollLeft{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0%);
    transform:translateX(0%);
    }

    50% {
      -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
      transform:translateX(-50%);
    }
     
    100% {
      -webkit-transform:translateX(0%);
      transform:translateX(0%);
    } 
 }
 
 @keyframes scrollRight{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    }
    
     50% {
      -webkit-transform:translateX(0%);
      transform:translateX(0%);
    }
     
    100% {
      -webkit-transform:translateX(50%);
      transform:translateX(50%);
    } 
 }
```

```html
<ul class="office-slider-list office-slider-list--1">
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="America/Chicago" data-cursor-text="Contact Chicago">Chicago</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Europe/London" data-cursor-text="Contact London">London</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="America/New_York" data-cursor-text="Contact New York">New York</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="America/Toronto" data-cursor-text="Contact Toronto">Toronto</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="America/New_York" data-cursor-text="Contact New Jersey">New Jersey</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="America/Chicago" data-cursor-text="Contact Chicago">Chicago</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Europe/London" data-cursor-text="Contact London">London</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="office-slider-list office-slider-list--2">
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Kolkata" data-cursor-text="Contact Chennai">Chennai</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Kolkata" data-cursor-text="Contact Pune">Pune</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Singapore" data-cursor-text="Contact Singapore">Singapore</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Kolkata" data-cursor-text="Contact Bangalore">Bangalore</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Tokyo" data-cursor-text="Contact Tokyo">Tokyo</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Kolkata" data-cursor-text="Contact Chennai">Chennai</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Kolkata" data-cursor-text="Contact Pune">Pune</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Singapore" data-cursor-text="Contact Singapore">Singapore</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Kolkata" data-cursor-text="Contact Bangalore">Bangalore</a></li>
</ul>
```

It is showing white space after full animation and I want both list to work opposite. Anyone can help me in this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: First get one of them working, then add reverse one. Focus on one problem per post

Comment: @TJ, Okay so Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`animation-direction: alternate;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction) Using its feature, it imitates animation on the turn. Thus, your animation will be simpler and shorter.

[`animation-direction: alternate-reverse;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction) You can select the animation start as ending and beginning using its feature. So you don't need to write two different animations that are the same.

The reason why the gap appears is due to your average content with '`justify-content: center`' after giving '`display: flex`'. When we remove it, I think the result will be the way you want it.

You can test it below. If you have any questions, please feel free to add a comment.

```css
.office-slider-list {
    font-size: 40px;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    will-change: transform;
}

.office-slider-list li {
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    letter-spacing: -.01em;
    color: #252227;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    margin-right: 2vw;
    line-height: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.office-slider-list.office-slider-list--1 {
    animation: scroll linear infinite;
    animation-duration: 2s !important;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

ul.office-slider-list.office-slider-list--2 {
    animation: scroll linear infinite;
    animation-duration: 2s !important;
    animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}

 @keyframes scroll{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0%);
    transform:translateX(0%);
    }

    100% {
      -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
      transform:translateX(-50%);
    }
 }
```

```html
<ul class="office-slider-list office-slider-list--1">
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="America/Chicago" data-cursor-text="Contact Chicago">Chicago</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Europe/London" data-cursor-text="Contact London">London</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="America/New_York" data-cursor-text="Contact New York">New York</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="America/Toronto" data-cursor-text="Contact Toronto">Toronto</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="America/New_York" data-cursor-text="Contact New Jersey">New Jersey</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="America/Chicago" data-cursor-text="Contact Chicago">Chicago</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Europe/London" data-cursor-text="Contact London">London</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="office-slider-list office-slider-list--2">
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Kolkata" data-cursor-text="Contact Chennai">Chennai</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Kolkata" data-cursor-text="Contact Pune">Pune</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Singapore" data-cursor-text="Contact Singapore">Singapore</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Kolkata" data-cursor-text="Contact Bangalore">Bangalore</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Tokyo" data-cursor-text="Contact Tokyo">Tokyo</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Kolkata" data-cursor-text="Contact Chennai">Chennai</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Kolkata" data-cursor-text="Contact Pune">Pune</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Singapore" data-cursor-text="Contact Singapore">Singapore</a></li>
    <li><a class="office-slider-city link-underline" data-timezone="Asia/Kolkata" data-cursor-text="Contact Bangalore">Bangalore</a></li>
</ul>
```

## Answer to your second question

It is quite possible to loop endlessly in one direction. **But there are two prerequisites for this.**

1. The number of elements that will be displayed on the screen.
2. The elements shown at the beginning on the screen repeat themselves at the end of the list.

In this way, you can get an infinite scrolling text group in one direction with **pure CSS codes** without using <del>**JavaScript codes**</del>.

Please review the example below and apply it to your project. If you run into problems, you can rewrite it.

```css
section {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  animation: slide linear infinite;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

.slider.reverse {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.slider div {
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
    /* Now we know how move it has to go (-200%) */
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="slider">
    <!-- Visible area (1) => on screen -->
    <div>Chicago</div>
    <div>London</div>
    <div>Toronto</div>
    <div>Singapore</div>
    <div>New Jersey</div>
    <!-- Visible area (1) <= on screen -->
    <!-- Visible area (2) => on screen -->
    <div>Bangalore</div>
    <div>Tokyo</div>
    <div>Toronto</div>
    <div>Pune</div>
    <div>Chennai</div>
    <!-- Visible area (2) <= on screen -->
    <!-- Visible duplicate of area (1) => on screen -->
    <div>Chicago</div>
    <div>London</div>
    <div>Chennai</div>
    <div>Singapore</div>
    <div>New Jersey</div>
    <!-- Visible duplicate of area (1) <= on screen -->
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="slider reverse">
    <!-- Visible area (1) => on screen -->
    <div>Chicago</div>
    <div>London</div>
    <div>Toronto</div>
    <div>Singapore</div>
    <div>New Jersey</div>
    <!-- Visible area (1) <= on screen -->
    <!-- Visible area (2) => on screen -->
    <div>Bangalore</div>
    <div>Tokyo</div>
    <div>Toronto</div>
    <div>Pune</div>
    <div>Chennai</div>
    <!-- Visible area (2) <= on screen -->
    <!-- Visible duplicate of area (1) => on screen -->
    <div>Chicago</div>
    <div>London</div>
    <div>Chennai</div>
    <div>Singapore</div>
    <div>New Jersey</div>
    <!-- Visible duplicate of area (1) <= on screen -->
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can we do the first row to always move forward and the second row always move opposite.

Comment: @RaghavKumar For this, I wrote you a new answer, added it under the same answer. Good luck with.